# How to return an array from reading a file?

Tags: arrays, go, readfile

I have two columns in a CSV file. I am accessing only the first column using the `SearchData()` function.

The problem is that I want to access the data as an array but when I return an array string in the `AccessData()` function and write the `products[0]` in the `SearchData()`, it gives me all the data by removing the bracket sign `[]` only and when I write `products[1]`, it gives me `runtime error: index out of range [1] with length 1`.

**Required result**

```
products[0] = First Item
products[1] = Second Item
...
so on
```

**Code**

```
func AccessData(number int) string {
    content, err := ioutil.ReadFile("products/data1.csv")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    Data := string(content)
    sliceData := strings.Split(Data, ",")
    return sliceData[number]
}

func SearchData(){
    for i := 0; i <= 34; i = i + 2 {
        products := AccessData(i)
        fmt.Println(products)
    }
}
```

Comment: @CeriseLimón How to do it?

Comment: Your question is incomplete without any example data. - you should write minimal verifiable examples for SO by removing external inputs - files, user input - and instead hard coding it in your example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```golang
func firstColumns(filename string) []string {
    f, err := os.Open(filename)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer f.Close()

    r := csv.NewReader(f)

    var result []string
    for {
        row, err := r.Read()
        if err != nil {
            if err == io.EOF {
                break
            }

            log.Fatal(err)
        }

        if len(row) > 0 {
            result = append(result, row[0])
        }
    }

    return result
}

func main() {
    data := firstColumns("products/data1.csv")
    fmt.Println(data)
    fmt.Println(data[1])
}
```

This turns the the first column of every row into a `[]string` which can be access index.

The output is:

```
[First item Second item]
Second item
```

Comment: It only reads 9 items. Although the first column contains 18 rows.

Comment: There might be an error while reading the file, I see I missed an `log.Fatal(err)` in my example, edited it. Do you get any errors?